# Override Third Party Extension in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, overrides

How can I Override a Third Party Extension?
The Path for the Extension is: *app/code/extension_company/extension/model/file.php*

Can I Override this php File by my custom Theme?

Comment: Please provide additional information about the exact circumstances and exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Without specifics, it's hard to solve your exact problem and ensure you're using the best approach. cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You can use  [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) at here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="extension_company/extension/model/file">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="overrider_the_third_part_file" sortOrder="10" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\FILE"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Use **after,before,around  method basic of your requirement**.

Comment: Ok, and where must i save the custom di.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the php file in your own custom module.
You can create your module and override the php file like this:

> app/code/Vendor/module_name/model/classname.php

You also need to create di.xml file at the following location wherein you will set the preference for your Class in classname.php

> app/code/Vendor/module_name/etc/di.xml

di.xml example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\ModuleName\Model\Classname" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Classname" />
</config>
```

classname.php example

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

class Classname extends \Magento\ModuleName\Model\Classname
{
   //your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: I followed same procedure but it's not working, could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549437/how-to-override-extend-rewrite-class-of-a-third-party-magento-2-x-extension